# JavaScript: Mi for se cancela por un setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo una especie de Scratch con un pseudo-lenguaje. Para poder ejecutar cada linea (uso `textarea`) uso una funcion para analizar el codigo, luego utilizo los resultados que vienen en una lista (commando, arg. Ej: wait 2). Mi problema es que al interpretar los comandos, hay uno en especial que es el wait, y para el wait utilizo `setTimeout()`, y el for lo ignora y sigue de largo, y la funcion queda obsoleta

```js
// Parts
let code = document.getElementById('code');
let playground = document.getElementById('playground');

// Elements
let execute = document.getElementById('execute');
let help = document.getElementById('help');
let player = document.getElementById('player');

// Functions

function analizeCode(code) {
    let lines = code.split('\n');
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        let line = lines[i];
        let command = line.split(' ')[0];
        let args = line.split(' ').slice(1);
        result.push({
            command: command,
            args: args
        });
    }
    return result;
}

// Execute code
execute.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let codeArea = document.getElementById('codeArea');
    let result = analizeCode(codeArea.value);
    console.log(result);

    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        let line = result[i];
        let command = line.command;
        let args = line.args;
        console.log(command);
        console.log(args);
        switch (command) {
            case 'move':
                document.getElementById('player').style.left = args[0] + 'px';
                document.getElementById('player').style.top = args[1] + 'px';         
                break;
            case 'rotate':
                document.getElementById('player').style.transform = 'rotate(' + args[0] + 'deg)';
                break;
            case 'wait':
                setTimeout(() => { 
                    analizeCode(codeArea.value);
                } , args[0] * 1000);
                break;
            case 'show':
                document.getElementById('player').style.display = 'block';
                break;
            case 'hide':
                document.getElementById('player').style.display = 'none';
                break;
            case 'repetir':
                for (let i = 0; i < args[0]; i++) {
                    analizeCode(codeArea.value);
                }
                break;
            case 'si':
                if (args[0] == 'true') {
                    analizeCode(codeArea.value);
                }
                break;
            case 'sino':
                analizeCode(codeArea.value);
                break;
            case 'fin':
                break;   
            default:
                console.log("No se pudo reconocer el codigo.");
        }
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

textarea { resize: none; font-family: monospace; }

#code { font-family: monospace; }

#execute {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#execute:hover { scale: 1.2; }

#execute:active { scale: 0.8; }

#help {
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Scratch - Nuevo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="code">
        <textarea id="codeArea" style="height: 200px;width: 100%;font-size: 20px;"></textarea>
    </div>

    <br><br><br><br>
    <div id="player" style="position: absolute;background-color: #f00;border: 10px solid #f00;background: #f00;border-radius: 50%;width: 25px;height: 25px;"></div>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <br>
    <center>
        <input type="button" id="execute" value="► Ejecutar" style="background-color: #0f0; border-radius: 10px; font-size: 40px">
        <br><br><input type="button" id="help" value="Apretá aca para ver como se programa"></input>
    </center>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por lo que entiendo quieres bloquear el flujo durante X segundos no? el setTimeout es una función asíncrona, no bloquea el proceso, simplemente ejecuta la función en X segundos en un "thread" aparte.

Comment: Podrîas poner un flag (variable true/false) para activar/desactivar lo que sea que quieres bloqueado, desactivarlo justo antes del setTimeout, y en la funcion reactivar el flag.

Comment: Mmm entiendo, pero no logro comprender como aplicarlo. Si no es molestia, podrias enseñarme como seria asi? Nunca he escuchado sobre ese termino. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y perdon por la tardanza

Comment: No entiendo lo que queres que suceda cuando se recibe el "wait", y no entiendo que se supone que haga la respuesta de analyzeCode, que en este momento es ignorada.

Comment: @Ricardo El wait es para esperar unos segundos, x eso el setTimeout(), y si que funciona analyzeCode, si pones hide funciona